# Adding dropdown to my action-bar title

Tags: android

```
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                         R.array.arrayItem);

bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, new OnNavigationListener() {    
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

I have been trying this one, but i don't get any drop-down or spinner here. Can anyone tell me what's the problem going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SpinnerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) interface is more suitable when using dropdown views (as it has the `getDropDownView()` method). From my understanding, `ArrayAdapter` is intended to provide single views (e.g. `TextView`s) for each array item, whereas `SpinnerAdapter` wraps them in a dropdown ("Spinner") menu.

Look at [this guide and the example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) on how to use it in your ActionBar.